# is it possible to debug my solution while debugging a test?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, nunit

I've got VS2010, nunit, and resharper. I've written a bunch of tests and when I debug those tests I can set breakpoints within the test code itself and those are hit, but no breakpoints within my solution itself are hit (the actual code that the test code is calling).
Is there a way to hit the breakpoints throughout my solution while debugging a test?

Answer (score 0):

This may happen sometimes if you have build errors and debugger is executing binaries from previous build ([Launch old version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cyhcc7zc.aspx)). This option can be disabled in Visual Studio:

Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Build And Run

> On Run, when build or deployment errors occur
>
> The message box is not displayed and the newly built version of the
>   application is not started. This option is set when you select Do not
>   show this dialog again in the message box, and then click Yes.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Tools->Options->Debugging->Enable Just My Code

Comment: I'm sorry, I made a mistake.  Have you tried unchecking this option?